# Snowflake Return records once based on combination of distinct column values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a data table like the following:

```
User ID Co_UserID   Name    Total Tickets
1514677 1377535    Jose        273013
1514677 1377535    Jose        273013
1514677 1377535    Jose        273013
1514677 1377535    Jose        273013
1514677 1377535    Jose        273013
212121  31313      Rob         21212
312312  234134     James       33
```

As you can see, I have duplicates based on **user ID** and **Co_userID** for Jose. I am trying to return distinct records where a combination of user_ID and co_userID appear once.

Desired Output:

```
User ID Co User ID  Name    Total Tickets
1514677 1377535 Jose         273013
212121  31313   Rob          21212
312312  234134  James        33
```

I tried running a query like the following, but selecting multiple distincts is not possible. Can someone advise?

```
SELECT distinct d.User_ID, distinct d.Co_userID, d.Name, d.Total_Tickets
From DATA d
```

Answer (score 5):

You only need one `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT distinct d.User_ID, d.Co_userID, d.Name, d.Total_Tickets
From DATA d;
```

`SELECT DISTINCT` is a single keyword in SQL (well, a modification of the `SELECT` clause).  There is not need for additional distincts.

This works for the data you have provided.  If you wanted one row for the first two columns -- and there are multiple values for the others, then use `QUALIFY:

```
SELECT d.User_ID, d.Co_userID, d.Name, d.Total_Tickets
FROM DATA d
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.User_ID, d.Co_userID ORDER BY d.User_id) = 1
```